# 2D game - tiny hiccups

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make my very first game. Its a simple endless scroller 2D game build with Unity 4.3.4. and C#.

Everything works fine, but if you look closely, you can see it has tiny hiccups. When you look closely at the left, the particles not moving smooth at all.

What am i doing wrong? It looks like there is something wrong with the framerate or something.

Live version: http://www.atticweb.nl/peekgame/ Download: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6929740/peekseek.rar

---

Could it be i'm giving him forward motion with changing the velocity? :
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 ( speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y )

Comment: What do you mean by smooth? They're fine as far as I can see. By the way, you should ask this on http://gamedev.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @MahanGM Unity questions are perfectly fine on Stack Overflow. There is no need for the user to go to Gamedev. Please only direct users to other sites if the question is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: very vague use of the term "hiccups". Please be specific so that others can help.

Comment: @Bart Well this is basically a game developing question and besides there is no code provided. If there was something to look at, I wouldn't have directed the OP.

Comment: Those issues make it not a good question on both sites. And therefore you still shouldn't migrate it @MahanGM.

Comment: @Bart I have no argument on the issues, but on the purpose. By providing code I meant we could actually accept the question as a code problem, but since there wasn't and I've had seen similar questions on gamedev, I thought it would be better for it to be discussed there as a theoretical topic. If there is any mistake by me, I apologize.

Comment: Could it be i'm giving him forward motion with changing the velocity? : rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 ( speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y )

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving something by say speed = 50; you will see jumps, because update() isn't called at exactly the same interval every time. You'll want to use Time.deltaTime * speed; This will make things move smoothly as it takes the time from the last refresh and multiplies by speed, so you result in 50 units per second generally.

Comment: But for the forward motion i use velocity on the ridgetbody2d, do i still need to use deltatime for that?

Answer (score 0):

A `RigidBody` is only updated every physics-frame, typically about 1/20th of a second.  This can cause jumpy-looking movement for fast-moving objects eg. if your game is 60 FPS, your physics objects stay in the same place for 3 frames at a time.

To combat this, set the [interpolation mode](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-interpolation.html) of the `RigidBody`:

- `RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate` will smooth the movement of the `RigidBody`, but cause it to reach its destination a few frames late
- `RigidbodyInterpolation.Extrapolate` will cause it to keep moving at the same velocity for the next few frames.  It will reach its destination at the correct frame, but it could still look jumpy if your velocity changes directions rapidly.

Setting the interpolation mode makes the computations more expensive, so you typically only want to do this for fast-moving objects or objects the player controls directly.